# unzip xxx.csv.gz to PROCEDURES_ICD.csv

Tags: linux, gzip

I would like to unzip a .csv.gz file to .csv. I cannot directly unzip because it will conduct an error: unable to expand (error 79: inappropriate file type or format). I tried the endorsed answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068197/how-to-unzip-the-file-name-csv-gz-files-to-csv/17068317#17068317 but it gives me a bunch of files with each file's name as one of the rows in the unzipped dataset. I am not sure how to unzip it. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Please provide the command line you are running.

Comment: the answer you've linked to describes how to uncompress *many* .csv.gz files, and if this doesn't work for your *one* file, then it won't work for a set of file containing your one file, either.

Comment: I use find . -name '*.csv.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 gzip -d as the command line. Not ssure why it does not work